# Installation troubleshooting

Tags: installation, boot, windows, launcher

i have installed ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop to a folder named ubuntu in C drive. However the OS does not show up in the initial boot sequence. Do i need to change the file location/ convert it into a cd/dvd, if so How?

Comment: You need to add some detail here.  How did you install Ubuntu?  I sounds like you want to run the wubi installer, but haven't actaully done so.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you installed Ubuntu to a "folder"? This might mean one of two things:

1) You used wubi to install Ubuntu (i never tried wubi so I cant help in this)
2) you mean a partition instead of a folder? (though this is unlikely since you mentioned "in C")

If you are attempting to install Ubuntu side by side to Windows (i.e; dual boot) then  you need to restart your computer & boot from the disk (or usb) & use the Ubuntu installer which guides you (note that there's a step where you need to create a partition for Ubuntu!)

Lots of resources are available online about this!

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you install it? Did you format a usb stick or cd? Or just copy some files somewhere?

To install Ubuntu:
Download the .iso [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Download [Universal Usb Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

Use Universal Usb to properly create a usb drive to boot from, then install.

Sorry if you've done all this, but your question isn't very clear.